# Redirect wildcard subdomain to main domain using c#

Tags: c#, iis, redirect, wildcard

Can someone guide me how to redirect wildcard subdomains to the main domain programmatically using IIS and C#?

Say if I have a domain called `www.example.com` and subdomain `test.exaple.com` or a wildcard subdomain `*.example.com` I want it to be redirected to the `www.example.com` domain. It needs to be done using C# and IIS.

Comment: This is built-in functionality of IIS (assuming your subdomains already point to your server), so why do you want to add something in C# to that?

Comment: C# adds a lot of overhead here.